# Force one drbd node to StandAlone

Tags: linux, hardware, drbd

I need to take a box that is part of 2-node DRBD cluster offline for hardware servicing.

How do I force the primary (the other?) DRBD node to StandAlone so that I can turn the other node down?

Just turn it off? Is it safe to do that?

Answer (score 6):

1. Stop DRBD

$drbd -stop

2. Gracefully shutdown Linux

$shutdown -h now

Comment: Thank you, but I left one thing out of the question - can I take the other node offline *without* stopping entire drbd resource? I mean, if a node fails physically, that's just what happens, so DRBD has to have some way of making that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Just turning it off is perfectly safe. Depending upon how things are setup it should be gracefully stopped (including a disconnect) either via a cluster resource manager, or a systemd unit, init script, etc.

If you do truly want to disconnect it before powering it off just issue a `drbdadm disconnect <resource>` to instruct DRBD to stop the connection and listener.